# How the second print statement gives compile time error?

Tags: java, iteration

The second print statement is giving compile time error. Please explain

```
public class mainClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {    
        final int a=10, b=20;

        while(a < b) {
            System.out.println("Hello");
        }
        System.out.println("World");
    } 
}
```

Comment: Always include the exact error you're getting.

Comment: Because as per your logic a will be always less than b and sop statement outside while will be unreachable

Answer (score 1):

The condition `a<b` always hold true.

The compiler detects that your program never end and the second print line will never be reached hence it throws the compile error

You might want to change your `while` to an `if` check

Comment: It's not that it is always true, it's that it is a compile time constant whose value is true. (For example, you could remove the `final`, and `a<b` would still always be true, but it's not a constant expression). Subtle difference, but the compile-time constant-ness is what the compiler uses to determine reachability.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be written as:

```
public class Answer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        while (10 < 20) { //always true, so loop is infinite
            System.out.println("Hello");
        }
        System.out.println("World"); //previous loop is infinite => this statement will never be reached
    }

}
```

BUT, if you write something like this:

```
public class Answer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a = 10, b = 20;

        while (a < b) {

            System.out.println("Hello");
            b--; //if you decrease var b, in some point while condition becomes false
        }
        System.out.println("World"); //AND this statement will be reached
    }

}
```

Please, notice that int b cannot be final!